# Create object using parentheses python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Difference between create instance of an objects by () and without parentheses?

Assume this is my simple class:

```
class ilist(list):
    t1 = "Test1"
    t2 = "Test2"
```

And making the instances to this two variables:

```
list1 = ilist()
list2 = ilist
```

When print the two instances

```
>>> list1
[]
>>> list2
<class '__main__.ilist'>
```

I can successfully access their attributes

```
>>> list1.test1
'Test1'
>>> list2.test1
'Test1'
```

And it shows error in list2 using a method append

```
>>> list1.append("Item1")
>>> list2.append("Item1")
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#64>", line 1, in <module>
list2.append("Item1")
TypeError: descriptor 'append' requires a 'list' object but received a 'str'
```

What is the difference not only in this simple example?

Comment: Only one of them creates an instance,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`list1 = ilist()` creates an object of the class. `list2 = ilist` makes a reference to the class itself. Classes are first-class objects in Python, which means they can be assigned just like any other object.

Because the attributes are part of the class, they're also part of the objects that are created with that class.

Answer (score 2):

When you are not calling the class (omitting the `()`), you are not making instances. You are creating another reference to the *class*. `()` calls a class to produce an instance.

Your `list2` variable is merely a reference to your `ilist` class object. That class object has both `t1` and `t1` attributes, so you can reference those. But only `list1` is an actual instance, produced by calling the class.

When looking up attributes on an instance, the class is consulted *as well*. So `list1` does not have the `t1` and `t2` attributes, but its class *does*.

You may want to consult the [Python tutorial on classes](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) again to see what the difference is between classes and instances.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't creating an instance of an object in your second example. You're just assigning the class `ilist` to a variable named `list2`, which is why `repr(list)` prints out its class name.

Answer (score 1):

To explain the actual error message: The same method is called in the second example, but methods should receive `self` as their first argument. If you are calling using an instance, it will be passed as the first argument; but here you are using the class, so it should be passed explicitly.

You are passing `"Item1"` as the first argument, but that's a string, not an `ilist`.

Answer (score 0):

(almost) Everything is an object in python, so `list1 = ilist()` is an object of type `ilist` and `ilist` and `list2 = ilist` are objects of type `type`